# Properly discontinuous action and Fundamental Domain

Tags: isometry

Does properly discontinuous action by a discrete group G on R^n necessarily have compact fundamental domain?

Definitions:

Properly discontinuous: For each x in R^n there is open neighborhood U of x such that gU and U does not intersect for all g in G (except identity)

(I am reading a proof of Bieberbach's theorems. The author uses the following conditions to define the group of isometries:

A group G of rigid motions in R^n is called crystallographic if

(i) for all t> 0 only finitely many $ \alpha \in G $ have the absolute value of translation part less than or equal to t. -- this is the consequence of discreteness condition, I assume.

(ii) there is some constant d such that for each $ x \in R^n $ there is an element $ \alpha \in G $  satisfying $ |a-x| \le d $ where a is the translation part of $ \alpha $

I am assuming that this second part follows from the properly discontinuous action of G. But I am unable to see the connection. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper discontinuity does imply the existence of a fundamental domain, at least in the case of an action by isometries. You can then take, as a fundamental domain, the *Dirichlet domain* defined as follows:

$$D := \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n | \forall g \in G, d(y, x) \leq d(y, gx) \}$$

where $x$ is some fixed choice of element of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> **Edit:** it is important that the point $x$ is chosen so that its stabiliser under the group action is trivial. If this is not the case then $D$ will fail to be a fundamental domain.
>
> Take, as a counter example, a group $G\le O(n)$ which fixes the origin. We then have by construction $d(y,0)=d(y,g(0))$ for all $g\in G$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore, taking $x=0$ would yield $D=\mathbb{R}^n$, but this is clearly not a fundamental domain unless $G$ is trivial.

(In the general case this statement is also true, but you have to use a different definition for proper discontinuity and possibly impose some additional conditions. The Dirichlet domain construction no longer works, so the proof is much harder.)

On the other hand, the assumption of having a *compact* fundamental domain is stronger than proper discontinuity. For example consider the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by translations (by integer multiples of, say, the first basis vector $e_1$). This action is properly discontinuous; but its fundamental domains are vertical strips of width $1$ and infinite height, so they are not compact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the second condition imply that the fundamental domain is compact?

(ii) there is some constant d such that for each x∈Rn there is an element α∈Gα satisfying |a−x|≤d where a is the translation part of α

Comment: If this second condition is true, what can you say about the Dirichlet domain with the base point $x = 0$? (Here $x$ refers to the $x$ in my formula, not the $x$ in your formula which is different.)

Comment: An important condition is missing from this answer, that the stabiliser of $x$ is trivial, otherwise $D$ is not a fundamental domain. I have submitted an edit discussing this

Comment: My edit was rejected, I assume because it constituted too significant a change to the original answer. I will submit a separate answer which corrects the error in this answer

Comment: I do not know why your edit was rejected - the point that you raise is absolutely valid. I just approved it (as OP, I can apparently override the moderators' decision). Too bad it all happened so fast!

Comment: I do not know why you changed $d(y,gx)$ to $d(x,gy)$, though. Obviously both work, but the original choice makes, in my opinion, for a clearer mental picture: you plot the orbit of $x$, and then you draw the region that is closer to $x$ than to any other orbit. I mean, it is easier to picture the orbit as being fixed and the sample point as a variable, rather than the other way round.

Comment: I guess for me it's the other way around that makes for a clearer picture. It fit more closely with my edit which is why I changed, it , but feel free to change it back. Thanks for approving the edit. I looked at your profile and it seemed you hadn't been active, and since the post was so old I went with trying to edit/re-answer rather than commenting and suggesting you edit your own answer - sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

*My answer follows on from that of @IliaSmilga, which is in general correct, but omits an important condition on the point $x$.*

> Proper discontinuity does imply the existence of a fundamental domain, at least in the case of an action by isometries. You can then take, as a fundamental domain, the *Dirichlet domain* defined as follows:
>
> $$D := \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n | \forall g \in G, d(y, x) \leq d(y, gx) \}$$
>
> where $x$ is some fixed element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for example $0$).

The point $x$ must be chosen so that its stabiliser is trivial.  If this is not the case then $D$ will fail to be a fundamental domain.

Take, as a counter example, a group $G≤O(n)$ which fixes the origin. Since every element of $G$ preserves the Euclidean inner product, we have that $d(0,y)=d(0,gy)$ for all $g\in G$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore, taking $x=0$ would yield $D=\mathbb{R}^n$, but this is clearly not a fundamental domain unless $G$ is trivial.