# Why don't I see any mention of fundamental domain in the context of non-discrete Lie Group acting on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $G$ be a **non-discrete** Lie Group acting ***properly*** on a Riemannian manifold $M$ by its isometries. When $G$ is discrete, there are plenty of literature on Fundamendal Domains (FD), but **a quick literature search shows *none* on FD when $G$ is *not* discrete, and is say a Lie Group of manifold dimension at least one**.

In what follows, $d_M$ is the metric on $M$ induced by the Riemannian metric $g$ on $M.$

My first question is:

1. **What's the reason behind the fact that we don't see any literature on FD when $G$ is non-discrete?**

Also, a very common FD used when $G$ is discrete is the Dirichlet Fundamental Domain $F(p_0)$ associated with the point $p_0\in M$, see for example: [this link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-56694-4_37), [this link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.11997.pdf), [this link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-1146-4_9), when $M:=\mathbb{H}^2, G$ a discrete subgroup of its isometry group, given by:

$$F(p_0):=\{p\in M: d_M(p,p_0)\le d_M(p, g.p_0)\forall g \in G\}$$

I also consulted this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251627/proper-discontinuity-and-existence-of-a-fundamental-domain), but in [this excellent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/251680/35936) given by Misha, the assumption remains the same: $G$ is discrete. Before asking my next questions, let me copy and paste the definition from Misha's answer there, so that this question is self-contained.

**Definition.** Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $G\times M\to M$ be a proper action of a discrete group. An open  subset $D\subset M$ is a fundamental domain for the action if:

1. The interior of the closure of $D$ equals $D$.
2. $G$-orbit of $cl(D)$ equals $M$.
3. $g(D)\cap D=\emptyset$ for all $g\in G -\{1\}$.
4. The collection of subsets $\{g cl(D): g\in G\}$ is locally finite.

**My subsequent questions are:**

2. Where exactly is the *discreteness assumption* playing a role to guarantee the existence of a fundamental domain, or proving that $F(p_0)$ above (or its interior, depending on the definition you choose to use) is a fundamental domain? Will it not respect the property 4) above, but will respect the other three if we assume $G$ is non-discrete?
3. What problem will we run into if we work with the subset $F(p_0):=\{p\in M: d_M(p,p_0)\le d_M(p, g.p_0)\forall g \in G\}?$ Will it fail to be a fundamental domain if $G$ is *not* discrete? A very [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408712/fundamental-domains-for-proper-lie-group-actions-on-smooth-manifolds) was earlier asked by *another* author here, but received no answer.

Comment: You have to change the definition to get something meaningful in this setting. You can start by reading about **slices** here:https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/slice+theorem

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks to your pointers, I've stared to take a look at the slices, and relevant stuff related to principal orbits.  It seems to me that the slices divide $M$ into disjoint pieces that're transversal to the orbits, that also divide $M$ like that. But what seems to be true also is that: the regular part $M^{*}$ of the manifold (union of principal orbits) should be a disjoint union of slices, is it always (or in nice cases) true? It seems so for $S^1$ action on $R^2,$ where the $M^{*}:=R^2\setminus \{0\}$ can be split into disjoint slices $\{c\vec{v}:c>0\}$ passing through $\vec{v}.$

Comment: The regular part $M^*$ gives a principal $G$-bundle $\pi: M^*\to M^*/G$. This bundle might be nontrivial, but if you take an open dense contractible subset $U\subset M^*/G$, the bundle over it will be trivial and you get a global slice on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ which is a submanifold of $M$. This is an analogue of a fundamental domain. There is an analogue of the Dirichlet construction since you can define $U$ as the complement to the cut-locus of a point.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you again for your comment. My apologies for this somewhat dumb question, but I've lost touch with fiber bundle for a while (I'll revise). Did you mean that the answer to my previous question is no in general, i.e. the regular part of M can't be necessarily written as the disjoint union of slices? 

Also, what did you mean by cut locus in the quotient $M/G,$ since the latter may not be a manifold?

Also, could you please give me a link to this Dirichlet construction you referred to? I searched it on the internet but couldn't find one. Thank you again!

Comment: Dirichlet construction is the one of a fundamental domain, which is closely related to the cut-locus in the case of manifolds of nonpositive curvature. The quotient $M^*/G$ is a manifold and one can put a complete Riemannian metric there. As for a global slice (or disjoint unuon of slices) on $M^*$, it depends on the exact meaning: If you allow slices of different dimensions, then yes, you can get it (countably many slices).

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose that you reword the definition of a fundamental domain by throwing away the discreteness requirement: just replace the phrase *proper action of a discrete group* by the phrase *proper action of a topological group*.

> **Theorem:** If $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, and if $G \times M$ is a proper action of a topological group, and if $G$ has a fundamental domain, then $G$ is discrete.

For the proof, assuming that $G$ is not discrete, I'll argue to a contradiction. Because of the failure of discreteness, there exists a sequence $g_i \in G$ of nonidentity elements of $G$, such that $g_i \ne g_i$ if $i \ne j$ and such that $g_i$ that converges to the identity element of $G$.

Pick a point $x \in D$.

By item 4, $x$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that the set
$$S_U = \{g \in G \mid g(cl(D)) \cap U \ne \emptyset\}
$$
is finite. But since $g_i$ converges the identity, it follows that $g_i(x)$ converges to $x$, and so there exists $I$ such that $i \ge I \implies g_i(x) \in U$. But $x \in D \in cl(D)$, and so if $i \ge I$ then $g_i(D) \cap U \ne \emptyset$. The set $S_U$ is therefore infinite, which is a contradiction.

Notice that the only portion of the definition I used is item 4. That item all alone is what enforces discreteness.

This answers your question 2. It also answers your question 1; there is little literature on non-existent objects. It also answers your question 3, because what my proof shows is that for *any* nonempty subset $D \subset M$, if $G$ is not discrete then the set $\{g(cl(D)) \mid g \in G\}$ is not locally finite.

Comment: many thanks for your answer, now I see more clearly how the two concepts are connected: $G$ being discrete and Axiom (iv): the collection consisting of the $G$-translates of the closures being locally finite.


But what if we drop the Axiom (iv) and keep the rest three axioms in the definition of the fundamental domain above? Will it not help us generalize the concept of fundamental domain for discrete groups to Lie groups?

Comment: In general, it's hard to guess wildly at how a mathematical concept will usefully generalize. If one *does* have some examples of generalization in mind, and perhaps some applications of those examples, that can sometimes drive the development of a useful generalization. If you have some such things in mind, you should say so. Otherwise, for the specific case of a fundamental domain, I have no idea what kind of generalization might be useful.